# How to run the particular file in absolute path?

Tags: linux, logstash, relative-path, absolute-path

I have Files called enum-pipeline-2.conf  enum-ruby-filter-2.rb  get_session_msgs_query.json  lookup.json, which I was running by giving ./file_name in my linux script. I wanted to run those files using absolute path.

When I am trying to find it

```
readlink -f get_session_msgs_query.json --->
/root/PWG/logstash-pipelines/enum/logstash_templates/get_session_msgs_query.json
```

This I am getting, Can anyone please help how to run it in linux?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to execute a script by using its full path?

Comment: @SimonDoppler Yes. before I was running it using ./file_name when i was doing it on relative path, now full path(absolute path) and how to run script in it.

Comment: Using the full path works (such as `/foo/bar/script` instead of `./script` from the `/foo/bar` directory), do you get an error message when you try it? You need to be aware that the script behavior may be dependent on its working directory (the directory from which you run it).

Comment: @SimonDoppler I did not try because I dont have small piece of idea even how to run it.
query_template => "./get_session_msgs_query.json", this is how i was running it. Now, 
 /root/PWG/logstash-pipelines/enum/logstash_templates/get_session_msgs_query.json this is its full path, I wanted to run this in my conf file. yes script behaviour is depending on its working directory that is why i wanted to run it using absolute path. Hope you get it.

Comment: What happens when you run `/root/PWG/logstash-pipelines/enum/logstash_templates/get_session_msgs_query.json`?

Comment: @SimonDoppler it is giving same result "nil".

Comment: If you are not running it from the same directory and the behavior changes, this is not a shell or Linux issue but a script issue (it probably makes assumptions on what working directory it is in).